# Importing Google Calendar Reminders to mac Apps

Tags: calendar, ical, reminders, google-calendar, google-sync

Is there any way to import reminders created in Google Calendar to ANY of the available free app in macOS Big Sur?

Ideally it would be nice to have a sync feature as well but I would be happy with just a single-time import from Google Calendar for reminders so that all future reminders can be created in the suggested app.

I am pretty sure that the native Reminders doesn't do that and neither does the Calendar app.

Answer (score 0):

`Calendar` → `preferences` → `accounts` → click on the `+` button, and add your Google account.

Comment: Please add more detail to your answer. I assume you are referring to the native Calendar app, but it is not clear from your answer. Also it is very short and without much explanation, further it is only a partial answer. It would be great if you could elaborate on that!

Comment: Adding Google Account via this method does not import **Reminders** but does import other things. My query is specifically related to importing Reminders.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the gTasks app, available in a free and a "pro" version from the App Store. It's a pretty good app and designed specifically to integrate with the Apple and Google environments.

I believe it has an auto-sync feature and should run on Big Sur.